# A different way of calculating the surface area of the sphere

Tags: calculus, spherical-geometry

I just don't understand this. I know $A_{sphere} = 4\pi r^2$ and the circumference $C_{sphere}  = 2\pi r$, so why can't I just sum up (integrate) all the circumferences to get the area? That is, why is
$$
\int_0^\pi C_{sphere} \ d\theta = \int_0^\pi 2\pi r\ d\theta = 2\pi^2 r \neq 2\pi r^2 = A_{sphere}
$$
I know I'm missing a core concept here, but it seems completely fine to take the integral of all the circumferences (i.e. sum of the infinitesimally thin circumferences) in the sphere to get the area.

Comment: What is the relationship between $r$ and $\theta$?

Comment: @Berci No I know that, but for these circles their radius is all the same - it is $r$. I'm thinking of all the great circles going through both poles, and summing them up.

Comment: If you sliced perpendicular to an axis, of course, it would work. But the surface area of a segment of a sphere, as you envision it, is not the circumference of a great circle times $\Delta\theta$; different portions of the arc sweep out area at different rates ($0$ at the pole, maximum at the equator).

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes I agree, but in the limit $\Delta\theta\to 0$, and that's a line - the great circle. That should still work in my opinion.

Comment: Not if you think about computing approximating Riemann sums! By your logic, the length of any differentiable curve will be the length of the line segment joining its endpoints!

Comment: One very immediate way of seeing that what you've written can't make any sense is to check the units. Surface area has units of length squared, whereas your result has units of length, because you mulitplied a length with an angle increment instead of a length increment to get the area increment. So it's not just that you used some constant rate at which area is being swept out instead of some variable rate; what you've written isn't even an area increment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you denote by $C_{sphere}$ should be called the *circumference of a circle*. Imagine that you stuck together many circles to form a cylinder of length $\pi$. Then
$$\int_{0}^{\pi} C_{sphere} \, d\theta$$
is the surface area of this cylinder (not counting the two disks at both ends of the cylinder). There is no reason why this should be equal to the surface area of a sphere!

The problem is that there is no way to slice the sphere to get "$\pi$" circles of radius $r$. If you try slicing an apple into many parallel slices, you will get circles of different sizes (most of them having radius less than $r$). Assume, you are slicing perpendicular to the stem and $\theta$ is the angle between the stem and the point you start a particular slice. Then you will get a circle of radius $r \sin \theta$. The length (or circumference) of this slice is therefore
$$2 \pi \cdot r \sin \theta.$$
If you measure how wide the skin is on this slice (not the slice itself!), you will get
$$r \, d\theta.$$
From this you can get the total area by integrating
$$\int_{0}^{\pi} 2 \pi r^2 \sin \theta \, d\theta = 4 \pi r^2.$$
[image]